# Example Groups with the same expectation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

A logged in user has access to a resource and can get there in different ways. I want to have an example group, that each test for the same expectation.

I put an `page.should have_content("...")` expectation in an `after(:each)` block, but that is not such a good solution: If I declare it pending, it fails anyway. And if it fails, the error appears (at first) white.

How should I write example groups that each have the same expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a shared example group:

```
describe 'foo' do
  shared_examples "bar" do
    it 'should ...' do
    end
  end

  context "when viewing in the first way" do
    before(:each) do
        ...
    end

    it_behaves_like 'bar'
  end

  context "when viewing in the second way" do
    before(:each) do
        ...
    end

    it_behaves_like 'bar'
  end
end
```

Within the before blocks you set things up so that the action is taken out in the correct way. Another way of doing this is to have your shared examples call a `do_foo` method and provide different implementations of `do_foo` in each context.

You can also have shared contexts if what you want to share is the setup stuff.

Comment: 8 years later I fund this and it helped me implement it in my code. The relish docs are good, but always helpful to see other examples.
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/example-groups/shared-examples